# Error when going through a for loop with multiple "if" conditions in pine script

Tags: loops, pine-script

I'm telling you, I had a previous version that worked with multiple conditions to execute an entry, I'll give you an example:

```
lo0 := deltaCloseMa0>=lo0CloseMa0Thresold and rsi>=lo0RsiThreshold
lo1 := deltaCloseMa0>=lo1CloseMa0Thresold and rsi>=lo1RsiThreshold and deltaCloseOpen>=lo1CloseOpenThreshold 
lo2 := ....
lo3 := ....
lo4 := ....
....
lo25 := ....
```

The problem comes from the fact that the code has grown substantially and now it is impossible to continue adding conditions to infinity, because it is not scalable.

A possible solution has occurred to me, which deals with evaluating the conditions one by one and then if all the ones that are enabled are met, executing the input.

I put the code fragment that I have written but I am not able to make it compile the script.

```
var entryOrderConditions = false, constructorMa0Cond = false, constructorRsiCond = false
var orderBuilder = array.new_bool(0)
if orderType    // If orderType is enable, then evaluate the conditions for long .. if disable, for short
    // LONG
    if barstate.isconfirmed and strategy.position_size == 0
        // ## Setup constructor
        if enableCloseToMa0
            if deltaCloseMa0 >= ma0CloseThreshold
                array.push(orderBuilder, true)
            else
                array.push(orderBuilder, false)
        if enableRsi
            if rsi >= rsiThreshold
                array.push(orderBuilder, true)
            else
                array.push(orderBuilder, false)
        
        for signal in orderBuilder
            if signal
                entryOrderConditions := true
            else
                entryOrderConditions := false
                break
```

The question is that the same conditions are not always enabled, nor is the tolerance threshold always the same, so they are dynamized above with inputs (bool, int, float...)

So I have to look for a flexible system that allows me to evaluate as many conditions as I want and is scalable enough not to have 100 input types defined in the code.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty solution:

I have tried with various types of arrays, with various ways of traversing them, with different checks, and I have even looked for a "switch" to filter... But nothing worked.

In the end I have found a solution that works, it is not the most elegant and cleanest code in the world but, it is functional, and I think I can't improve it.

I'm open to suggestions if anyone reads this and thinks there's a better way to do it.

A little philosophy of own creation,

> Sometimes, the best solution is not the most pleasant

Even so, it is still more scalable than at the beginning.

```
float constructorMa0Cond = na
float constructorRsiCond = na
if orderType
    // LONG
    if barstate.isconfirmed and strategy.position_size == 0
        // ## Setup constructor
        if enableCloseToMa0
            if deltaCloseMa0 >= ma0CloseThreshold
                constructorMa0Cond := 1
            else
                constructorMa0Cond := 0
        if enableRsi
            if rsi >= rsiThreshold
                constructorRsiCond := 1
            else
                constructorRsiCond := 0

        for i = 0 to 1
            if i == 0
                if not na(constructorMa0Cond)
                    if constructorMa0Cond
                        entryOrderConditions := true
                    else
                        entryOrderConditions := false
                        break
            else if i == 1
                if not na(constructorRsiCond)
                    if constructorRsiCond
                        entryOrderConditions := true
                    else
                        entryOrderConditions := false
                        break
```